# python - extract values of a dataframe 1 based on a range of values(times) from another dataframe 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do something that seems quite easy on excel using `vlookup`. All the times bellow are of `timedelta datatype` . Couldn't find a solution that fit me by google searching the errors.

`DF1 (bellow)` is my main DataFrame one value is Arrival time.

```
+--------+------+
|Arrival | idBin|
+--------+------+
|10:01:40|  nan |
|10:03:12|  nan |
|10:05:55|  nan |
|10:05:10|  nan |
+--------+------+
```

`DF2(bellow)` is my parameters Dataframe with **1k+ time ranges** (manually creating a dictionary seems impractical).

```
+--------+--------+------+
|start   |end     |idBin |
+--------+--------+------+
|10:00:00|10:00:30|  1   |
|10:00:31|10:01:00|  2   |
|10:01:01|10:01:30|  3   |
|10:01:31|10:02:00|  4   |
+--------+--------+------+
```

What I need is to get `DF2.idBin` into `DF1.idBin` where `DF1.arrival` between `DF2.start` and `DF2.end`

**What I tried so far:**

`**.loc**` > returns `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

```
    pd.DataFrame.loc[ (df1['arrival'] >= df2['start']) 
                     & (df1['arrival'] <= df2['end']), 'idBin'] = df2['idBin']
```

`**date_range()**` so I could transform it into dictionary, but return `TypeError: Cannot convert input [0 days 10:00:00] of type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> to Timestamp`

```
dt_range = pd.date_range(start=df2['start'].min(), end=df2['end'].max(), name=df2['idBin'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
x = pd.Series(df2['idBin'], pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['start'], df2['end']))
inds = np.array([np.flatnonzero(np.array([k in z for z in x.index])) for k in df.Arrival])
bools = [arr.size>0 for arr in inds]
df.loc[bools, 'idBin'] = df2.iloc[[ind[0] for ind in inds[bools]]].idBin.values
```

Comment: Hello Rafael, thanks for your input, it's almost doing what's expected! It is indeed returning the values from the `df2['idBin']`, but not when the range starts with 1 second; i.e.: `11:05:01` or `13:00:31`. In those cases it's returning nans! I'll try to fiddle a little, but this will probably be the answer... any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Fixed the issue by simply remaking the `df2['start']`, rounding the values down by 1 second.

Comment: Oh, and btw @RafaelC, is there something I could read to understand what you did there?

Answer (score 0):

```
DF2_intervals = pd.Series(DF2['idBin'], pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(DF2['start'], DF2['end']))
DF1['idBin'] = DF1['Arrival'].map(DF2_intervals)
```

You can also turn that into one line to be more efficient, should you wish to.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Got all `np.nan`s here :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it also got me only nans here. Printing DF2_intervals show that the interval is there, but the last column isn't returning the bin values, only nans

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if there is a pre_built solution but you can do something similar to what you tried but in a UDF and then apply this to the column in df1 and have that output a new column.

```
def match_idbin(date, df2):
    idbin = df2.loc[(df2['start'] > date)&
                (df2['end'] < date),'idBin']
    return idbin

df1['idBin'] = df1['Arrival'].apply(lambda x: match_idbin(x, df2))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input, but running it returns one of two errors, if `df1['idBin'] = np.nan` = `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (0,234) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,234)`, if the `df1['idBin']` is not initialized it returns `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1`